# Need value from dataset displayed in Tkinter on matplotlib using mouseevent

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter, mouseevent

I'm using a `mouseevent` to grab the x-axis value (which is in `datetime` format). However, when I get the value, it is the exact location that the user clicked, not the x-axis value from the nearest point.

e.g. There's a point at `11/15/2014 17:15:30`. The user clicks as close as they can at `11/15/2014 17:15:27.543928+00:00`. I need the program to realize it wants the nearest point so I can index that exact value later. I'm looking for the fastest/most efficient option--I don't want to have to loop through the entire list looking for the closest match, but that is the only solution I currently see. Optimally, when the user clicked, it would simply report the x-value of the nearest point.

I've added the portion of the code I'm taking about below. I've also added the portion where I actually plot the data (obviously all of this is within a class

```
#Importing modules
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import numpy as np
from images_to_list import images_to_list
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename, askdirectory
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

class App:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.line,=self.ax.plot(tft[self.event_num],tf1[self.event_num],'.',picker=5) #Plotting the voltage data from mat 1
        self.line2, = self.ax.plot(tft[self.event_num],tf2[self.event_num],'.',picker=5)

    def onpick(self,event):        
        x = event.mouseevent.xdata
        y = event.mouseevent.ydata
        self.actual = mdates.num2date(x) #because x is in numpy.float64
        print self.actual
        #self.image_ind = tft.index(self.actual)
        #self.image_scroll.set(self.image_ind)
        dataind = event.ind[0]    

#Action Creating the UI and running the program
app = App(extra)
app.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', app.onpick)
extra.mainloop()
```

Comment: If you x-data is sorted you can use a binary search to find the closest and can use a `kdtree` in higher dimensions.

Comment: I'm fairly new to python--can you leave an example of how to do that in the answer section?